# knockoutJS Binding Not Working

Tags: knockout.js

I have a JS Model like this

```
 define(,
function () {
    return function(trusteeType, accessRight) {
        var self = this;

        self.trusteeType = ko.observable(trusteeType);
        self.accessRight = ko.observable(accessRight);
    }
});
```

the model is injected into a JS file (RequireJS) and used like such

```
define(["durandal/app", "plugins/router", "./models/permissionsModel"],
function (app, router, permissionsModel) {
```

And I use the model like this

```
self.selectedUserToModifyPopup = ko.observable();

            self.modifyAccessRights = function (data) {

            console.log(data);
            self.selectedUserToModify = data;

            self.selectedUserToModifyPopup = new permissionsModel(
                    data.trusteeType(),
                    data.accessRight());

            console.log(self.selectedUserToModifyPopup);

            self.openEditPermissions();
        };
```

The problem is, in the HTML code I cannot access a property to bind to.. Nothing happens. No errors. Nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Through the console.log(data) I can see my observable DOES have data in it.

EDIT:
I think this has something to do with my permissionsModel but Im not sure whats wrong with it?

Comment: Nobody has any ideas?

Comment: did you ko.applyBindings() ?